# C# correct alternative for SQL Numeric

Tags: c#, sql, .net, algorithm, numeric

I've been playing around with Numerics and the c# 128-bit counterpart decimal and noticed some differences. For one, C# decimal is 128-bit, while SQL numeric occupies an extra byte.

What I was wondering is: what would be the 'correct' (fast) SQL compliant way to implement a Numeric/Decimal in C# (just as an 'academic question')?

Oh and to make the question a bit harder:

- Of course I want the data structure to occupy as little bytes as possible.
- Like the normal 'decimal' in C#, I want to be able to add, subtract, divide and multiply.

Because a numeric with 17 bytes is the hardest, this is the one that really interests me. The other precisions are just variations on it that probably require another struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal.aspx) already offers this. It offers the arithmetic as well.

Comment: Note this from MSDN: SqlDecimal has different underlying data structures from its corresponding .NET Framework Decimal data type. Decimal has no concept of precision. It uses 3 bytes to store the actual data, and therefore has a maximum scale of 28 and a range of ((-2^96 to 2^96) / 10^(0 to 28)). SqlDecimal has both precision and scale. It uses 4 unsigned 4-byte integers to store the actual data, and therefore has maximum precision and scale of 38. The data range is - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1.

Comment: @IainBallard that should read as 'warning: SqlDecimal is *correct* as in it matches the SQL semantics'

Comment: @RemusRusanu Nice, I didn't know about this class. Even though SqlDecimal uses 20 bytes rather than 17, I suppose in SQL these 3 bytes of metadata are stored in the table schema, which results in the 17 bytes. (I know it doesn't matter since they are allocated anyways, but we're talking academically here. :-)

Comment: That is a very good observation, SQL knows the precision and scale from the metadata. Not sure what the 3rd byte is for (16 bytes for 4 int32s, 1 for sign , 1 precision, 1 scale, 1 for? perhaps 4-byte alignment )

Comment: For implementation examples, you can look at Hive's [Decimal128](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/9775c351a6235783c989bc86b5d54f166d9f8f62/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/common/type/Decimal128.java).